# After what instruction the thread migrates to another logical processor?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pthreads

I want to know at what point in the program execution flow (more exactly, after what instruction), the thread migrates from logical processor 0 to logical processor 1. I use `SetProcessAffinityMask()` to set the desired logical processor.

I tried to set via `SetProcessAffinityMask()` all the threads to run on logical processor 0 and, inside the thread function, when the thread is running, to change the affinity mask and call again `SetProcessAffinityMask()`, in order to make the threads run on logical processor 1 at that moment. It works, because I am using prints that display the logical processor number using `GetCurrentProcessorNumber()`. I suppose that the thread changes logical processor after I use the 2nd call of `SetProcessAffinityMask()`, but I am not sure.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void* tmgr_function(void* arg)
{
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD_PTR processAffinityMask = 1;
    BOOL success = SetProcessAffinityMask(process, processAffinityMask);
    
    printf("Thread runs on core %d\n", GetCurrentProcessorNumber());
    processAffinityMask = 2;

    success = SetProcessAffinityMask(process, processAffinityMask);
   
    printf("Thread runs on core %d\n", GetCurrentProcessorNumber());
    
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int arg;
    
    long sum = 0;
    
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, tmgr_function, &arg);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pthreads and Windows mix?

Comment: @user17732522 Yes because I was familiar with pthreads, but i needed logical processor management functions from Windows.

Comment: On Windows, the pthread library is just a wrapper around existing Windows API functions, there is no need to use it and it may even be counterproductive.

Comment: The actual migration of the thread from one core to another is likely handled on a third kernel thread in response to the second `SetProcessAffinityMask` call, which essentially bans the thread from core 1.

Comment: Inside SetProcessAffinityMask, and so what ?